# If Jesus had his second coming, were Yivo's angel-creatures a lie?

Tags: futurama

In the movie, [The Beast with a Billion Backs](http://theinfosphere.org/The_beast_with_a_billion_backs), [Yivo](http://theinfosphere.org/Yivo) explains that his body and the [Jakabirds](http://theinfosphere.org/Jakabird) that inhabit him inspired vision of heaven for Humanity. However it has already been revealed in an earlier episode that Jesus' second coming occurred and erased most of the world's videotape.

Does this mean that Yivo was lying about the coincidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yivo's explanation is a lie only if you interpret the second coming of Jesus as meaning that all Christian beliefs about Heaven are verified as true (i.e. the idea of Heaven was inspired by God alone).

Since we don't know exactly what happened during Jesus' second coming (aside from the wanton destruction of outdated media) then we can't assume that the mere *occurrence* of the second coming automatically proves as true *every* aspect of Christian belief. It's possible that when Jesus showed up he could have set some things straight, like telling everyone:

> Hey, you know all those ideas you have about Heaven? Yeah... that was interference from a neighboring universe. Sorry for the confusion. Oh, and about this whole "the Earth is only 8000 years old" thing...

In other words, it's possible to imagine a scenario where both concepts can coexist: Jesus is the Son of God and returns a second time, but Yivo is the one who gave form to what was adopted as the Christian idea of Heaven (meaning Jesus might have some 'splaining to do).

<sub>*Please interpret all of the above purely as humor. I mean no disrespect to anyone. ;)*</sub>